# Remote PowerShell script hangs when running `git push`

Tags: git, powershell, winrm, winrs

I've run `Enter-PSSession` successfully to connect to a remote server, and run several commands successfully too, like `git add -u` and `git commit -m "xxx"` etc.

but when trying to push the code using `git push` command, the shell then blocked forever unless exit with "Ctrl+C".

however I can remotely run `git push` from `remote desktop program` successfully without inputing any password.

is it because inputing username and password is needed in this case?

any way to solve/workaround it? thanks

Comment: What authentication do you have on your GIT server? Where/how is your GIT hosted? It's probably waiting for you enter enter credentials that you don't have to locally because they're cached.

Comment: should be, the "credential.helper" is "manager"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the username and password in the Git URL, either by configuring it in the config in advance:

```
git config remote.origin.url https://username:password@somegiturl.com/somerepo/somerepo.git
```

or within your push:

```
git push https://username:password@somegiturl.com/somerepo/somerepo.git
```

Comment: the second command does not work, where i changed https to http, because our server uses http right now.


````
git : fatal: Win32Exception encountered.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Win32Exception encountered.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   Failed to write credentials
Everything up-to-date
````

Comment: the first command may cause credential problem because the computer is shared by a team

Comment: Oh, actually the second command works, thought it reports some error. thanks, this solves my problem

Comment: Yeah beware git has a tendency to return non error states in a way that PowerShell thinks is an error.